# How to make a single program span two monitors when in TwinView

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to make emacs span two screens but the size is automatically resized to a single screen. I'm running a NVidia card in TwinView, with Ubuntu 10.04. I'm having this problem with other programs also.

Comment: Multimonitor setups on Ubuntu with nVidia cards, ohh the pain :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same setup.  I have found three ways, none of which are ideal.

1. Disable compiz and use metacity instead.
2. You can add the following lines to the "Screen" section of your xorg.conf file to treat both monitors as one big display:
   `Option         "Xinerama" "1"

   Option         "NoTwinViewXineramaInfo" "True"`

   After you log out and log back in, your monitors will act as one screen.  Note that you will get some unexpected behavior such as your gnome-panels spanning both monitors and you will also lose the ability to maximize on just one monitor.
3. This one seems like a bug.  Drag the window all the way to the left (or right depending on your setup) with the majority of the window off the screen.  Grab the visible edge of the window and stretch it out across both monitors.  Leave as much empty space as you dragged off screen.  Now drag it back so it's fully on both screens.  It seems like at least half the window must be off the screen for this trick to work.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot after I achieve stability on my new machine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simplistic suggestion (and you've probably thought of it), but can you just drag the emacs window so that it overlaps both screens and then drag-resize the window to the outside edges of your screens? You would have to keep it in windowed mode, of course (i.e., not maximized).

Comment: If it I make the window to big it snaps to the edge of one of the screens. At least for emacs.